# bittorrent client: ttorrent doesn't work

Tags: java, android, bittorrent

I want to start simple download using saved .torrent file on ("/sdcard/file.torrent").

I've tried **ttorrent**, because it's most simple bittorrent client.

[ttorrent on github.com](https://github.com/turn/ttorrent#client-code)
So I've tried this code, but had errors...

```
String filePath = "/sdcard/file.torrent";
String downPath = "/sdcard/A";                  

Client client = new Client (
    InetAddress.getLocalHost(),
    SharedTorrent.fromFile(
    new File(filePath),
    new File(downPath)
    )
);

client.setMaxDownloadRate(0.0);
client.setMaxUploadRate(0.0);           
client.download();
client.share(0);         
client.waitForCompletion();
```

Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(5992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(5992): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHex
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent.byteArrayToHexString(Torrent.java:415)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent.<init>(Torrent.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.turn.ttorrent.client.SharedTorrent.<init>(SharedTorrent.java:175)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.turn.ttorrent.client.SharedTorrent.<init>(SharedTorrent.java:159)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.turn.ttorrent.client.SharedTorrent.fromFile(SharedTorrent.java:239)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.torrentsearch.activities.ResultList.onContextItemSelected(ResultList.java:435)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2647)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3921)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:193)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:934)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1280)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3071)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3973)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The Apache Commons library is not part of the Android SDK. You need to bundle it with your app or at least the classes needed by ttorrent.

Comment: I have all libs and classes, everything is imported correctly.
Classes I've grab from https://github.com/turn/ttorrent#client-code

Comment: You can see it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4urnqythdckq9gc/Untitled.png

Comment: Hm... can you check if the linked library contains that method "encodeHex"? Another possible reason may be that the Apache Commons JAR was not compiled with a Java 1.6 compiler. That's unfortunately a requirement for the Android tool chain to work. Another possible explanation may be code obfuscation through ProGuard. You'd need to protect these Apache commons method names from being changed

Comment: Ok, problem was in apache-commons lib.
I used 1.8 (latest version), but for this ttorrent client 1.2 is needed.

Comment: client.setMaxDownloadRate(0.0); 0.0 set no limit for download speed.
But download speed is to low, Android uTorrent has much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in apache-commons lib. I used 1.8 (latest version), but for this ttorrent client [1.2 version](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/codec/) is needed.

`client.setMaxDownloadRate(0.0);` 

0.0 set no limit for download speed. But download speed is to low, Android uTorrent has much more.